# Spell out the current time for accessibility time labels

Tags: ios, accessibility

I'm working on an app where I need to have labels that show a time, localized to the user's locale. This all works fine by using the `NSDateFormatter()` class.

```
let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
let timeStr: String = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(time)
```

But the string that is generated by `NSDateFormatter()` is not properly spoken by VoiceOver. It's quite alright for US English but for example not for Dutch (my native language).

I then tried to use the `NSDateComponentsFormatter()` class and specifying `NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle.SpellOut` for the `unitsStyle` property.

```
let timeComponentFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
timeComponentFormatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle.SpellOut
let accessibilityTimeStr: String = timeComponentFormatter.stringFromDateComponents(timeComponents)!
```

Although this generates a nice string that can be spoken by VoiceOver, it's not as a native speaker would say the time. And although it's in the correct language, it's not formatted to the cultural conventions for the user's region.

When I tap on the time on the lock screen with VoiceOver enabled, it speaks the time correctly as a native speaker would say it, in every language that I tried. So there must be something in iOS that can generate the correct string that can be spoken by VoiceOver.

I can not find a public API that does this. Am I missing something or is this maybe a private API ?

Comment: I have the same question. It seems like it's something that would need to be handled by the system as it is quite a complex task.

Comment: I've submitted an enhancement request to Apple to make this API publicly available.

Comment: So did I, just last night! :-)

Comment: hey, did you receive any feedback by apple in the meantime?

Comment: Nope :-(  No comments or reply on the radar.

Comment: I still have bugs unresolved with no reply which I reported 15 years ago. So don't hold your breath! Basically, if it fits the company strategy, it will get fixed sooner, if it doesn't, it may never get fixed.

Comment: it's a shame that ~5 years later, this is still a private API

Comment: A tangent, perhaps, but just want to link to this discussion at the w3c pronunciation task force. I think the lack of movement on this from speech synth vendors is partly because they're waiting for the task force to formulate a spec. https://github.com/w3c/pronunciation/issues/101

Comment: In the meanwhile, isn’t there an independent library that turns times into full sentences, which in turn you can expose as the accessible name?